# Correct way to define a RetrieveAPIView view class

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

After reading the documentation of django-rest-framework, this is what I have done:
serializers.py:

```
class UserRegistrationDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            User._meta.pk.name,
        )
```

views.py

```
class RegistrationDetailView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    serializer_class = serializers.UserRegistrationDetailSerializer
    permission_classes = (
        permissions.AllowAny,
    )
    lookup_field='email'

    def get_queryset(self):
        email = self.kwargs.get('email')
        user = get_object_or_404(User, email = email)
        if user:
            if settings.get('SEND_ACTIVATION_EMAIL'):
                self.send_activation_email(user)
            elif settings.get('SEND_CONFIRMATION_EMAIL'):
                self.send_confirmation_email(user)

        return User.objects.all()
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^register/(?P<email>\w+|[\w.%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})/$', views.RegistrationDetailView.as_view(), name='register_detail'),
]
```

I have defined `def get_queryset(self):`  instead of just providing the `queryset` variable because I wanted to send an email to the user if the user exists in the database. It works as required but since I am new to django-rest-framework, I am not quite sure if this is the right way to do this. Am I doing anything unnecessary here?

Comment: What problem are you having exactly? It isn't clear from your question what you would like help with. It appears you have successfully written a way to retrieve user data without issue.

Comment: I mean it's odd that you are calling `send_activation_email` on `GET` requests, without any other checks (any user can call that endpoint and call that method endlessly) but if that's what you want that's cool.

Comment: @ashley email is being sent only after a user with that email is present in the database.

Comment: this question is super relevant although bad shaped